# Export data from PDF forms to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I have a .pdf form I have created in Adobe Acrobat XI Pro. The form will be distributed and individuals will complete the form and email me a copy at various times.

I need to get the information from the form into an Excel spreadsheet as I receive the forms back.

Is that possible?

Comment: http://www.myengineeringworld.net/2013/10/read-and-write-pdf-forms-from-excel-vba.html

Answer (score 0):

Direct answer: "Yes"

A bit more verbose answer: There are several possibilities.

a) Use the "Merge Data Files into Spreadsheet" function, which can be found in the Forms pane in the Tools panel of Acrobat XI (and in the More… dropdown in the Prepare Forms Tool in Acrobat DC). There you specify from which files you want to extract the data, and Acrobat creates an according table.

This is quick and easy, and can process a whole batch of files, but it has the issue that you have no control over the fields you want to export and their order.

b) Use the doc.exportAsText() method on the forms; this will create a tab-delimited file, which you then can merge into your spreadsheet. This would be file per file, but you could create an Action which does run on a whole folder.

c) Use some logic to assemble a tab-delimited text, and create and then export a Data Object (which would be a tab-delimited file, as in case b). This gives you maximum control, and you can even export "calculated" data, which does not exist as such in the form, and/or have full control over the format of an exported field contents. This too is file per file, and could be turned into an Action.